# Table in Latex with picture and a lot of items

Tags: image, latex

I'm trying to add a huge table (30 items) with image, but I've 2 problems, first of all the text stay on the bottom of the cell not at the middle as you can see in the image bellow.

The second issue is the length of the tabular, I would like this table be on more than one page.

Anyone have a solution ?
[image: image of the problem]

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Id} & Name                                                                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Figure} \\ \hline
1                        & Press imaginary a button                                                                & \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{gesture/Tup.PNG}                  \\ \hline
2                        & Double press an imaginary button                                                        &  \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{gesture/Tup.PNG}                 \\ \hline
3                        & Close the fist                                                                          & \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{gesture/closeFist.PNG}             \\ \hline
4                        & Open the fist                                                                           & \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{gesture/openFist.PNG}              \\ \hline
5                        & Touch the ring                                                                          & \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{gesture/touchRing.PNG}            \\ \hline
6                        & Touch 2 times the ring                                                                  & \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{gesture/touchRing2.PNG}           \\ \hline
7                        & Draw letter V                                                                           & \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{gesture/V.PNG}                    \\ \hline
8                        & Draw letter X                                                                           & \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{gesture/X.PNG}                    \\ \hline
9                        & Draw question Mark                                                                      & \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{gesture/right.PNG}                \\ \hline
10                       & Swipe right                                                                             & \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{gesture/right.PNG}                \\ \hline
11                       & Swipe up                                                                                & \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{gesture/up.PNG}                   \\ \hline
12                       & Thumbs up                                                                               & \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{gesture/Tup.PNG}                  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Maybe a table is the wrong tool for the job? Tables are great to compare rows or columns to each other, but this doesn't seem to be the case in your example.

Comment: I need to represent 30 moves by a name, a picture and an ID, I've to use a table (It's for a school work)

Answer (score 1):

- to change the vertical alignment of images, you can use the `adjustbox` package
- to spread the table across multiple pages, have a look at the `longtable` package

or

- use the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}


\begin{longtblr}{
  colspec={Q[valign=b]Q[valign=b]Q[valign=h]},
  row{1}={halign=c},
  vlines,
  hlines
}
Id & Name                                                                             & Figure \\
1                        & Press imaginary a button                                                                & \includegraphics{example-image-duck}                  \\ 
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]